# jquery animated UL / li

Tags: jquery, html-lists, slide, animated

looking for simple script to animate my UL like on this site (slide, up old LI, and down new li)
http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_40268/

i Tried: http://jsfiddle.net/kndd9/1/

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: You need to try something more like [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x8JyJ/1/)..

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery slideDown/slideUp instead of animate.

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Comment: ok, but, how button know which div is visibled to hide, i know how do, up/down div, but, i dont know, i have 1 visibled div, and click button 2, and first div is sliding up, and another sliding down..

Comment: check fiddle posted by adeneo

Comment: ok, but it cant by slide function, it must by something like that 
animate({'top' : '-='+435},350).animate({'top' : '+='+400},350).animate({'top' : '+='+35},80); but this cone doesnt work there